# python mean between file

Tags: python, list, numpy

I create a list of more than a thousand file (Basically now I have a list with the name of the file) now in order to make the man I thought to do something like this (suppose asch file have 20 lines):

```
matrix = np.zeros((len(file_list),10))
```

then I'm going to charge the matrix .. with something like :

```py
for i,j in zip(len(file_list)) :
    matrix[i].append(np.genfromtxt('name1',usecols=(1,)))
```

Now is there a way not to define the number of file's line ???

then .. how can i make a mean between this file ??

Ops I see that numpy array have not append ..how can I do

Comment: you don't append numpy array, just change it in place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can just store them in a list:

```
My_list = []
for i,j in zip(len(file_list)) :
    My_list.append(np.genfromtxt('name1',usecols=(1,)))
```

Assuming that all your files have the same number of lines and columns, you can then convert it to a numpy array:

```
My_list = np.array(My_list)
```

`My_list` is now a numpy array, with dimensions corresponding to the size of the loaded files + one corresponding to the number of files.

Note that I did not check the way you're loading files.

Comment: But I have to make a mean from sevral files ! how can I do this ?

Comment: You can then use `np.mean()` on `My_list` which is now a numpy array, over the axis you want (depending on if you want to calculate the mean of each file, or averaging the files between them)