# Matrix of files

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I would like to create a matrix from files using (for collecting using `genfromtxt`)

I wrote this small piece of code ... but looks does not works at all

```
array[0].append(np.genfromtxt('alpha_mean/alpha_75/alphas.000521604.dat',usecols=(0,)))
```

Where `alphas.000521604.dat` is 4 columns data number.

During execute this command everything looks works but if I try for example to do:

```py
array=[ [0] for i in range(1)  ]
array[0].append(np.genfromtxt('alpha_mean/alpha_75/alphas.000521604.dat',usecols=(0,)))
array[0][4]
```

Outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

and I really don't know why ... can somebody help me out please?

But when we are speak about 3D white:

```
array=[] 
array.append(genfromtxt'file',usecols=(0,)) t
```

This works and is not only one index array ...

Comment: You appended only one element so index 4 don't exist, only 0 and 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python mean between file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64046611/python-mean-between-file)

Comment: Don't post twice the same question at 1-hour intervals: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64046611/python-mean-between-file/64048697?noredirect=1#comment113259357_64048697

Answer (score 0):

You can easily see the mistake if you print the intermediate state of the `array` variable

```
>>> array = [[0] for _ in range(1)]
>>> array
[[0]]
# 'array' is a list with one element, which is a list with one element as well,
# and that single element is the integer 0

>>> array[0]
[0, ]
# 'array' is a list with one element, so this shows that that element is
# a list with also 1 elements

>>> array[0].append('something')
>>> array
[[0, 'something']]
# the nested list has gotten a second element, which for this example is
# the string 'something'

>>> array[0]
[0, 'something']
# 'array' is a list with one element, so this shows that that element is
# a list with now 2 elements

>>> array[0][4]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
# this fails because 'array[0]' is a list with only 2 elements, not 5;
# 'array[0][4]' tries to access the fifth element (indexing starts at 0)
```